# How to change a URL that is configured inside a library?

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, openid-connect

Context: I need to configure OIDC using Django to allow my application to be accessed by users.

Problem: I'm using a library called [mozilla-django-oidc](https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-django-oidc/blob/master/docs/settings.rst) that is pretty straight-forward, but when I test the configuration, it keeps returning the following error:
[400 - Invalid redirect_uri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kALd.png)

Cause: As I tested in Postman, this error occurs because the callback URL is wrong. When I searched more deeply mozilla-django-oidc, I've found it sets a standard URL path for callback (/oidc/callback/) which is not the URL allowed by the OIDC we need to access.

**Key Question #1**: How can I modify the mozilla-django-oidc code so that the standard callback URL path is what I need it to be?

**Key Question #2**: Is there anyway I can make these changes in my code, instead of mozilla-django-oidc?

Below are some settings of my Django code:

My Django - views.py

```
# Mozila OIDC configuration settings
OIDC_OP_AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
OIDC_OP_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
OIDC_OP_USER_ENDPOINT = "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
OIDC_RP_CLIENT_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
OIDC_RP_CLIENT_SECRET = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "https://myurl.com"
```

My Django - settings.py

```
# Add 'mozilla_django_oidc' to INSTALLED_APPS
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'mozilla_django_oidc',  # Load after auth
    # ...
)

# Add 'mozilla_django_oidc' authentication backend
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mozilla_django_oidc.auth.OIDCAuthenticationBackend',
    # ...
)
```

My Django - urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    # ...
    url(r'^oidc/', include('mozilla_django_oidc.urls')),
    # ...
)
```

mozilla-django-oidc - urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^callback/$', OIDCCallbackClass.as_view(),
        name='oidc_authentication_callback'),
    url(r'^authenticate/$', OIDCAuthenticateClass.as_view(),
        name='oidc_authentication_init'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.OIDCLogoutView.as_view(), name='oidc_logout'),
]
```

Other parts of mozilla-django-oidc library can be found at https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-django-oidc/tree/master/mozilla_django_oidc

Comment: Reading [docs](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/mozilla-django-oidc/stable/mozilla-django-oidc.pdf): _When using a custom callback view, it is generally a good idea to subclass the default OIDCAuthenticationCallbackView and override the methods you want to change._ Did you try to inherit from [`OIDCAuthenticationCallbackView`](https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-django-oidc/blob/master/mozilla_django_oidc/views.py#L28) and set your custom url path ?

Comment: Redirect URL(s) is standard configuration of OIDC client, so you don't need to code at all. Just configure used OIDC client properly in your Identity Provider UI.